# Problems with drawing polynomial approximation graph for Bessel function of the first kind of order zero

Tags: matlab

I need to use **Matlab** to draw the following graph

[image]

I can draw `J0(x)` graph, the matter is drawing the polynomial approximation lines. For example, for n = 2, I tried the following codes:

```
x = [0:0.01:10];
y = besselj(0,x);
p = polyfit(x,y,2);
x1 = linspace(0,2);
y1 = besselj(0,x1);
f1 = polyval(p,x1);
figure
plot(x,y,'o')
hold on
plot(x1,y1)
plot(x1,f1,'r--')
```

The graph doesn't come as expected. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my codes? Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial you get with `polyfit` is a **least-square-error** approximation over the specified range. On the other hand, the polynomials in the picture seem to be **Taylor** approximations about 0.

So, you basically need to replace

> `p = polyfit(x,y,2);`

by something like

```
syms s % symbolic variable
n = 2; % desired order
p = sym2poly(taylor(besselj(0, s), 'Order', n+1)); % Taylor polynomial
```

(or define the polynomial manually if you don't have the Symbolic Toolbox).

Thus:

```
x = 0:0.01:10.5;
y = besselj(0,x);
figure
plot(x, y, 'linewidth', 1.5)
%%p = polyfit(x,y,2);
for n = 2:2:20
    syms s;
    p = sym2poly(taylor(besselj(0, s), 'Order', n+1)); % Taylor polynomial
    x1 = linspace(0,10.5,200);
    f1 = polyval(p,x1);
    hold on
    plot(x1, f1, '-', 'linewidth', .6)
end
axis([0 10.5 -2 2])
```

[image]